# Flash CS4 & AS3: How to add/use hyperlinks in externally loaded dynamic text

Tags: actionscript-3, hyperlink, flash-cs4

The basic setup is this: I am loading text from external text file into a "news & events" style dynamic text field, which is nested within a movieclip.

Like so:

```
var newsloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("vzm_news_text.txt"));
newsloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
    var loadedText:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    homeContent.newsText.condenseWhite = true;
    homeContent.newsText.htmlText = loadedText.data;
    homeContent.scrollBar.update();
}
```

My external .txt file contains simple html formatting tags and loads/displays perfectly.

What I can't figure out is: How do I make active links within the text that gets loaded?

I tried adding A HREF tag in the .txt file, but the link and everything after it doesn't display. I'm sure this is simple, and I've searched quite a bit with no luck. I am a novice learning as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your href line doesn't include any &, " or ' that might be breaking the text variable.

Alternatively, if you can load .xml instead of .txt you can enclose your news on CDATA tags.

```
<newstext>
<![CDATA[<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/"> www.google.com</a>]]>
</newstext>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sticking with my .txt file for now, I tried the href again, paying close attention to the symbols you mention, and now the link text and regular text after it are showing. Plus the pointer turns into the hand when it hovers over the link text. However, nothing happens when I click it. Also, the link text doesn't display as an active link color. I would also like the link to open in a _blank window.

Comment: target="_blank" will handle the blank window. The link not working will probably be to do with you testing the swf locally. Embed the swf into a html file and upload it to a web server and test it from there. If you want to format the text with hover state styling you might be able to do that by applying a stylesheet to the text area. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html

Comment: It works! Thanks for the help. In the end, I am loading an external CSS file as I can use it for multiple text fields in my scene.